# customizing ion nav bar in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

How do I customize `ion-nav-bar`.

```
<div class=" bar bar-header navbar-fixed-top navbar-header ">
<div class="container row">
           <div class="col-33">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <h1>ROCK 'N' GRILL<br>
                        <span>Pitampura New Delhi...</span></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <div class="col-50 topPull">
            <button class="button-icon" on-swipe-down="changeSlide()"><img src="img/topImg.jpg"></button>
                           </div>
            <div class="col-33 menuItems">

                            <a class="menuItems" href="#">Menu1</a>

                            <a class="menuItems" href="#">Menu2</a>

            </div>           
        </div>               

</div>
```

However, this is a static header. I would like it to convert it to ion-nav-bar but it breaks with it. How do I customize it to be used as ion-nav-bar and not header ?

Demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/000722ac6197

Comment: Instead of `col-33` use `col-40` and if you're not well aware of its *grid-system* then study [**ionic-grid**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-explicit)

Comment: Thank you for the tip but that's kind of irrelevant to my question, isn't it?